# Is it enough to mention which browser you want to run the tests with in serenity.properties file?

Tags: serenity-bdd, serenity-js

Is it enough to mention which browser you want to run the tests with in serenity.properties file ?
Like...

Chrome Browser Testing
webdriver.driver=chrome
headless.mode = true

```
drivers.windows.webdriver.chrome.driver = src/test/resources/webdriver/windows/chromedriver.exe
drivers.mac.webdriver.chrome.driver = src/test/resources/webdriver/mac/chromedriver
drivers.linux.webdriver.chrome.driver = src/test/resources/webdriver/linux/chromedriver

Firefox Browser Testing
webdriver.driver=firefox
gecko.firefox.options = {"args": ["-headless"]}
drivers.mac.webdriver.gecko.driver = src/test/resources/webdriver/mac/geckodriver
drivers.linux.webdriver.firefox.driver = src/test/resources/webdriver/linux/geckodriver
```

and invoke the test using command line like...
mvn clean verify -DuserId='xxx' -Dpasscode='xxx'

OR SHOULD I MENTION ALSO..

``mvn clean verify -Dwebdriver.driver=browser -DuserId='xxx' -Dpasscode='xxx'

Will Serenity infer it from properties file alone ?
Because when I don't give any browser in command prompt, and mention only firefox in properties file, it is looking for ChromeDriver and failing, whose path is properly given in properties file already.
Which option takes priority or which overrides which ?
I agree these are silly little questions !!

Answer (score 0):

The command line will override the property file.

So if you want to remove the `webdriver.driver` from the command line and move it into the properties that will work fine, it will grab from the properties file. 
Then you can overwrite it later using the command line `webdriver.driver`.

Also I should note that almost all commands can be moved into the serenity properties file. Also you can setup multiple properties files for the different setups, devices, and tests you need to run.

I run over 15 different properties files for different settings on different devices. Then all I have to do is reference the property file in the command via: `-Dproperties=properties/desktop.properties`

Also one more note, my preference is to leave the `webdriver.driver` in the command line it makes it easier to run the same tests on the same device with different browser setups. I then create simple bash scripts that run my acceptance tests, smoke tests, regression tests, and does it on several different devices from desktop to mobile and then tests on the different browsers on the different nodes. But to each their own.